# Keep x versions of a file in Folder - delete rest

Tags: powershell, backup

I have backup process that makes a copy of files and appending system time at the end. Date stamp indicates when the file was received via FTP (ddMMYYYYhhmmss).

```
fileName1.ZIP02062015090653
fileName1.ZIP01062015090653
fileName1.ZIP31052015090653
fileName1.ZIP29052015090653
fileName1.ZIP28052015090653
fileName1.ZIP21052015090653
fileName2.ZIP02062015090653
fileName3.ZIP02062015090653
reportName1.PDF02062015090653
reportNameX.TXT02062015090653
etc..
```

I need the script to keep the 5 most recent versions of each file.

```
i.e. fileName1.ZIP21052015090653 <- this should get deleted.
```

I was trying to work of a script below but it deletes everything after 5th file..

```
gci C:\temp\ -Recurse| where{-not $_.PsIsContainer}| sort CreationTime -desc| 
    select -Skip 5| Remove-Item -Force
```

I don't mind if script uses fileName, dateModified, creationTime or DateStamp - I'd like to be able to keep 5 versions of each file and blow away oldest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
gci C:\temp\ -Recurse | 
where{-not $_.PsIsContainer} |
Group-Object basename |
foreach {
  $_.Group |
  sort CreationTime -Descending |
  Select -Skip 5 |
   foreach { Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force -WhatIf }
  }
```

That will group the files by the basename, then sort/delete within each group.
Remove the -Whatif if the results look right and re-run to actually delete the files.

Comment: Tanks a lot! It works perfect for some of my folders but I seem to struggle for new month files:

I have following files:
`xxx.ZIP01062015120652`
`xxx.ZIP02062015090653`
`xxx.ZIP15052015170549`
`xxx.ZIP19052015020509`
`xxx.ZIP20052015050542`
`xxx.ZIP20052015200551`
`xxx.ZIP21052015110551`
`xxx.ZIP22052015080515`
`xxx.ZIP26052015090554`
`xxx.ZIP27052015080555`
`xxx.ZIP28052015070511`
`xxx.ZIP29052015090535`


The script seem to attempt to delete 01 and 02 June.

`xxx.ZIP02062015090653`
`xxx.ZIP01062015120652`

As these are part of 5 most recent I'd need to keep them.
Appreciate your help!

Comment: It's making the decision on what files to delete based on creation time, so the file names are irrelevant except for grouping.  You'll have to debug that from your side.

Comment: Great! I appreciate all your help it works now. I've replaced `CreationTime` with `LastWriteTime` not sure why but it helped. I was worried that `MMdd` instead `ddMM` date stamp is causing sort problem but its all good now.